Image viewer with continuous stream of photos without having to click on each folder ("infinite scroll")
I'm looking for a free lightweight image viewer that allows to browse an entire collection of photos (e.g. D:\PHOTOS\ which has thousands of sub or sub-subfolders), without having to click on each subfolder to view them:
Picasa is an example of such software, but is sadly discontinued:

The viewer should offer a continuous stream of photos, without having to manually click on each of these subfolders:
D:\PHOTOS\2022\2022-01
D:\PHOTOS\2022\2022-02
D:\PHOTOS\2022\2022-02\HOME\
...
D:\PHOTOS\2022\2024-07

Ideally, just a single key, such as SPACE (in the case of Picasa) should be able to scroll the collection from beginning to end.

You can do this with e.g. XnView MP.
It has a Show files in subfolders button in toolbar, while in folder view:


This is interesting. But let's say you have 100 GB of photos. To browse continuously the whole library, you have to click on the parent folder, e.g. D:\PHOTOS, and enable Show files in subfolders as you suggested. But then you cannot quickly go to D:\PHOTOS\2018-05 for example, you have no way to go there, except scrolling during minutes... The only way to go to this folder is to click on D:\PHOTOS\2018-05 on the left panel folders tree, but then you lose the continous stream of the whole library, do you see what I mean?

Second thing: when using this feature, the GUI is often non-responsive / frozen, with high CPU usage. Is there a way to prevent this to happen? Example: you double click on a .JPG, there is a rotating cursor, and the image is finally opened in a new tab 10 seconds later... Probably because the CPU is busy pre-caching the whole library? (I tried disabling the catalog, but it's the same thing)

@Basj for 1st comment, that's how Infinite scroll normally works. Not sure what else you have on mind - I guess sort of clickable side menu with moving to specific "anchors" that represent folders, but you should include that as a requirement then. Second - yeah, not the most optimal implementation of it and not much you can do, unfortunately. It works fine with a bigger photo folder on my machine, but ofc it depends on CPU etc.

Thanks for your feedback @Destroy666. About the 1st point, Picasa handles it very well: when you click on a subfolder, it automatically scrolls to it, but then you can still continue to browse the whole library (you are not limited to the subfolder you clicked on), that's a small detail but very important, great UX ;)
